# how to submit form from jQuery and navigate to the page?

Tags: php, jquery

I have two php pages. Page 1 contains one form which i submitted with jQuery. Page 2 is form query page. I want to read all the data from Page 2 after submitting from page 1 through navigation. My following code does not work as I expected.

Page 1:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "requestProcessor.php",
data: "fname="+ fname +"&amp; lname="+ lname,
success: function(){

window.location.href = "requestProcessor.php";

}
});
```

Page 2: requestProcessor.php

```
<?php
require("db/phpsql_info.php");

echo htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));
echo htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));
?>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your data parameter to:

```
data: { fname: fname, lname: lname }
```

It's more readable.

2nd, it does not make sense what you are doing. You are posting data to requestProcessor.php, then after that you send the user to requestProcessor.php (which is then a GET). This loses all the POST data from before of course as it's the equivalent of just typing requestProcessor.php into your URL bar.

If you want to go from page 1 to page 2 and see the data POSTed then just submit your form on page 1 to requestProcessor.php directly.

Else, if you want to show the result of page 2 after the POST, then send the response to some div on the current page.

```
success: function(response) {
    $("#some-div").html(response);
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve though if I am honest.